NS_ERROR_NET_TIMEOUT error on downloading js file for site load
I host a panel on my server. It was working and I could browse it already, but it could not be loaded for the last two days. I can ping my server and also I can make a telnet connection successfully to my server from all of the ISPs I am using, but when I am trying to browse the panel from one of my ISPs it returns an NS_ERROR_NET_TIMEOUT error.
I browse my panel using its IP:PORT, not a domain.
traceroute to <MY_IP_ADDRESS> (46.8.236.80), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets

 1  _gateway (192.168.1.1)  1.187 ms  1.096 ms  12.389 ms<br/>
 2  100.104.127.255 (100.104.127.255)  15.578 ms  15.868 ms  15.838 ms<br/>
 3  10.88.71.129 (10.88.71.129)  16.004 ms  16.171 ms  16.523 ms<br/>
 4  172.16.74.25 (172.16.74.25)  20.288 ms  21.804 ms  22.930 ms<br/>
 5  10.22.29.62 (10.22.29.62)  24.052 ms  27.044 ms  27.360 ms<br/>
 6  10.22.29.65 (10.22.29.65)  30.123 ms  12.684 ms  16.270 ms<br/>
 7  193.111.235.102 (193.111.235.102)  17.153 ms  17.411 ms  17.763 ms<br/>
 8  10.21.249.201 (10.21.249.201)  18.478 ms  20.270 ms  20.574 ms<br/>
 9  10.202.7.130 (10.202.7.130)  22.210 ms  22.599 ms  24.820 ms<br/>
10  213.144.184.56 (213.144.184.56)  100.551 ms ix-et-4-0-5-0.tcore2.fnm-frankfurt.as6453.net (195.219.87.198)  108.226 ms 193.251.252.153 (193.251.252.153)  100.829 ms<br/>
11  * ae15.francoforte34.fra.seabone.net (89.221.34.251)  109.043 ms ae304-0.ffttr7.frankfurt.opentransit.net (193.251.133.3)  108.498 ms<br/>
12  e0-34.core2.fra1.he.net (216.66.88.113)  110.262 ms  85.733 ms if-ae-9-2.tcore2.fr0-frankfurt.as6453.net (5.23.30.17)  87.899 ms<br/>
13  80.231.65.2 (80.231.65.2)  96.630 ms  100.212 ms *<br/>
14  netnod-ix-ge-a-sth-1500.he.net (194.68.123.187)  131.884 ms *  129.424 ms<br/>
15  port-channel4.core2.hel1.he.net (184.104.192.106)  102.696 ms gw-as51765.retn.net (87.245.248.193)  115.962 ms port-channel4.core2.hel1.he.net (184.104.192.106)  90.697 ms<br/>
16  oy-creanova-hosting-solutions-ltd.e0-49.switch1.hel1.he.net (184.104.203.133)  118.591 ms  118.343 ms *<br/>
17  * * <MY_IP_ADDRESS> (46.8.236.80)  120.949 ms<br/>

My Ubuntu release details:
   Distributor ID:    Ubuntu
   Description:   Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
   Release:   22.04
   Codename:  jammy
